# OPERACIONES CON JAVASCRIP EN TIEMPO REAL

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un combobox de opciones a,b y c y dos input tipo date donde ingresan fechas , ya que necesito calcular un valor según la opción que seleccionan, el caso es que me hace la formula cada vez que seleccionan la fecha pero necesito remplazar por cada vez que seleccionen la opción y mantener las fechas

Con este código calculo el valor que necesito pero necesito que al seleccionar a , b o c me cambie el resultado en prima anual

Select de opciones (es dinámico)

```
   <label>Opciones</label>
           <select  id = "opcion"  name = "opcion"  class = "form-control"  required = "required" >
           <option value="">Seleccione una opciòn</option>
           </select>
```

Inicio vigencia

```
<label >Inicio Vigencia</label>
      <input id="arr" type="date" name="inicio_vigencia" onchange="cal()" class="form-control" onkeydown="return false" >
```

Fin vigencia

```
<label>Fin Vigencia</label>
      <input id="dep" type="date" name="fin_vigencia" onchange="cal()" class="form-control">
```

prima total

```
  <label>Prima Total</label>
                    <input type="number" name="prima_total" class="form-control" id="total" readonly>
```

el calculo ya esta y lo hace bien solo necesito que me actualice el campo prima total segun la opcion seleccionada este es el codigo javascrip

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetDays() {
        var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("dep").value);
        var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("arr").value);
        var months = dropdt.getMonth() - pickdt.getMonth() + (12 * (dropdt.getFullYear() -          pickdt.getFullYear())); if(dropdt.getDate() < pickdt.getDate()){ months--; } return months;
    }
    
    function cal() {
        if (document.getElementById("dep")) {
            var el = document.getElementById("meses");
        el.value = GetDays();
        el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
        }
    }
    
    function getvalue() {
        var meses = document.getElementById("meses").value;
        var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
        
        var result =  Math.round(( meses * valor ) / 12);
        document.getElementById("total").value = result;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Francisco Núñez

Comment: hola no me queda claro lo que quieres hacer. puedes dar una mejor explicacion un poco mas detallada paso a paso que es lo que hace el usuario y que esperas que ocurra???

Comment: Primero necesito que seleccione un plan, luego una opcion despues establezca un incio vigencia , finalmente un fin vigencia lo que me arroja es cantidad de meses valor uno y valor dos segun la seleccion que escoja en opciones y por ultimo un resultado final, necesito que cuando el usuario seleccione a, b o c de la lista de opciones me actualice el resultado final ya que se deben mantener las fechas seleccionadas solo cambiaria eso

Comment: edita la pregunta ... no se que es: un plan que es  incio vigencia,  fin vigencia

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez allí están todos los campos